# How do I write my temperature data to Windows Azure's Sqldatabase?

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm new to Raspberry PI and need help on this part as I need to write my temperature data to Windows Azure's Sqldatabase.

```
import smbus
import time
import datetime

#SMBus(0) - Raspberry Pi Model A
#SMBus(1) - Raspberry Pi Model B

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

#I2C address of sensor
address = 0x48

def temperature():
rvalue0 = bus.read_word_data(address,0)
rvalue1 = (rvalue0 & 0xff00) >> 8
rvalue2 = rvalue0 & 0x00ff
rvalue = (((rvalue2 * 256) + rvalue1) >> 4 ) *.0625 #print rvalue1, rvalue2
return rvalue

print("Temperature Data Logger\n")

while True:

#Open Log File
f=open('tempdata.txt','a')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
outvalue = temperature()
outstring = str(timestamp)+"  "+str(outvalue)+" C "+str(outvalue*1.8+32)+" F"+"\n" 
print outstring
f.write(outstring)
f.close()

#log temperature every 60 seconds
time.sleep(60)
```

I'm only able to write it out as text file but don't know how to write it to Windows Azure's Sqldatabase which I have created in management portal.

Comment: This answer suggests using [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/ "pyodbc"): [How to connect python to SQL Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229551/how-to-connect-python-to-sql-azure/13230376#13230376 "How to connect python to SQL Azure?")

Comment: That link is for Windows and not from Raspberry PI

Comment: On your raspberry, install freetds and pyodbc, then use connection string that @scruss mentioned.

Comment: gurcanoztuk, could you guide me on what to type to install freetds and pyodbc cause I can't seems to find the package inside Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? What have you searched for? Both freetds and pyodbc show up in any `apt-cache search` I care to do.

This might get you started:

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-bin freetds-dev python-pymssql python-pyodbc python-sqlalchemy tdsodbc unixodbc-bin unixodbc-dev
```

There's some possibly helpful discussion here: [Connect to MSSQL using FreeTDS / ODBC in Python.](https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1293636)

Are you familiar enough with Python's database management? I'd strongly suggest you try setting up something which talks to a local SQLite database before jumping into the hairy weirdness that is Azure. Otherwise, this just seems like we're doing your homework for you …