# How to set ID for multiple sensors like LED, Temperature Sensor and etc?

Tags: raspbian, python, sensor

I would like to know how to set a custom ID to sensors like LED, Temperature Sensor and etc.

Example:
Like 1 LED sensor, not smart LED.
Only can display real time data and nothing else.
So I want to set a custom ID like int or string something to that LED sensor.
So it will be able to display ID and real time data.

Hope you guys could help me out with it, thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: I don't understand.  Could you give an example?

Comment: I have add an example, joan. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: Can you confirm that you mean I2C sensors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your [other questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19628/how-do-i-write-my-temperature-data-to-windows-azures-sqldatabase), I assume we're talking about I²C sensors, although I have no Idea what an "LED Sensor" might be. (Display, maybe?).

Still, if we're talking I²C, the address is a feature of the hardware, so you usually cannot set it manually. There might be a few contacts on your sensor which can be bridged to have it respond to a new address, though. See [this link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-led-backpack/changing-i2c-address) for more detailed information on Adafruit's LED Display.

If you have a rather expensive device, the address may also be programmed into some sort of memory - to change it, please refer to the device's manual. (Those devices are not common, so I don't think you'll have one of these)

Here's some more information about addresses in I²C: [edaboard.com](http://www.edaboard.com/thread224396.html)